# Php: Cannot seem to access array property in object

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I have a class called Member. I am trying to add a multidimensional array as a property like so:

```
class Member {

public $name;
public $inheritingMembers;

public function __construct($name, $family) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->inheritingMembers = $this->findInheritingMembers($family, $name);
}

function findInheritingMembers($array, $keySearch) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        if ($key == $keySearch){
            return $item['children'];
        } else {
            if (is_array($item))
                $this->findInheritingMembers($item, $keySearch);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

The function "findInherititngMembers" returns a multidimensional array which I can see with var_dump(). The problem is, I cannot seem to assign this array as the inheritingMembers property of the Member object.

Comment: `return $this->findInheritingMembers($item, $keySearch);`.

Comment: The array is returning correctly. The problem is assigning it to the property in the constructor.

Comment: [I tested this](http://pastebin.com/5TW1FJ3C) and it seems you do need to `return $this->findInheritingMembers($item, $keySearch)`. You are saying it isn't assigning correctly. What does `var_dump($this->inheritingMembers)` give you after you've made a new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need another return in your recursive function:

```
function findInheritingMembers($array, $keySearch) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item){
        if ($key == $keySearch){
            return $item['children'];
        } else {
            if (is_array($item))
                return $this->findInheritingMembers($item, $keySearch);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The array is returning correctly. The problem is assigning it to the property in the constructor.

Comment: @OllyTenerife: Yeah, but if you get one level deeper (in the else block) you are not returning anything at all. Is this the desired output? 
Have you tried my approach?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, if it doesn't match the first key it immediately goes one level deeper into the sub-array, without iterating over the others.